# I need to key in 3 integers and store them in an array

Tags: java

I am very new to Java but I have had some experience in programming with Visual Basic. This is what I have so far:

```
class Assignment11 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int array[] = new int[] {0,0,0};
        System.out.println("Input first number: ");
        array[0]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input second number: ");
        array[1]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input third number: ");
        array[2]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(array[0]);
    }
}
```

I want the program to say Input First Number and then read the value that is keyed in and store it in an array. What is the code to do this?

Comment: Your code already sort of does this, but you haven't declared nor initialized your scan variable. Thus that code shouldn't compile. Is this "borrowed" code?

Comment: No it wasn't borrowed. How do I initialize a scan variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Scanner...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int array[] = new int[3];
System.out.println("Input first number: ");
array[0]= scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input second number: ");
array[1]= scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input third number: ");
array[2]= scan.nextInt();
System.out.println(array[0]);
System.out.println(array[1]);
System.out.println(array[2]);
```

Comment: Where would I put in text to ask for input?

Comment: @user3089304 In a print statement?

Comment: It is saying illegal start of expression on "import"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    class Assignment11 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int array[] = new int[] {0,0,0};
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//this will wait for user input
        System.out.println("Input first number: ");//user will input the first num
        array[0]= scan.nextInt();//scanner will read the input and put into array
        System.out.println("Input second number: ");
        array[1]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input third number: ");
        array[2]= scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(array[0]);
    }
   }
```